# How can I get unity-2d-launcher to integrate with Awesome WM?

Tags: unity-2d, awesome

I really like the unity launcher, but in Awesome it only displays on Tag 1, and sometimes pops up behind other windows. Has anyone figured out a way to get this to work?

Comment: Set up a rule in `rc.lua` and make the laucher sticky.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: I am, indeed, but there don't seem to be any answers. Marco's comment above isn't very helpful, either--I know I have to do something with rc.lua, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: @Jon, How did you even get the launcher to run in awesome in the first place?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Autostarting it in `rc.lua` doesn't work?

Comment: None of this works in 12.04, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the suggestion by Marco in his comment, make the Unity launcher sticky.  Look in your `rc.lua` file (which should be in `~/.config/awesome/`) for the section that starts with:

```
-- {{{ Rules
awful.rules.rules = {
```

and then add the following awful rule

```
{ rule = { class = "Unity-2d-launcher" },
properties = { sticky = true } },
```

For example, you can add that rule right before the last line of the section which is `-- }}}`.  Save your changes and before restarting Awesome, remember to type `awesome -k` in the terminal to check and confirm the correctness of the syntax of your `rc.lua`.